# Custom ACL for EMR Hive output objects written to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, acl, emr

set fs.s3.canned.acl=BucketOwnerFullControl;

above line is an example of configuring emr's hive jobs to write objects to s3 using canned ACL (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-s3-acls.html)

I was wondering if I can have custom ACL in the same way.

Use case: 
EMR writes to S3 (regionA) which is then replicated to regionB. And Athena in RegionB to query the replicated objects. Inspite of RegionB being the owner of the bucket, the objects from regionA replicated under this bucket are not owned by RegionB.

So if anyone knows a way to set the ACL of the objects to allow read by cross account, I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EMR doesn't support writing objects with custom ACLs to s3 at the moment.